# Running Emacs ispell command doesn't ask confirmation to save to private dictionary

Tags: emacs, lisp, aspell, ispell

Everytime I run ispell-buffer and add things to the private dictionary. It asks me confirmation whether I want to save it or not at the end. Can I turn this off?? So it doesn't ask me the confirmation and just automatically saves it.

Then on a side note in addition to that. After I add something to the personal dictionary it doesn't seem to unmark the red underline until next time I pass over the word. Can I have ispell immediately rescan the document after running it so these red underlines disappear. I have saved the word in the private dictionary but still won't remove it. It is just quite distracting.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added

```
(setq ispell-silently-savep t)
```

to the .emacs file.

Rupert's answer let me know the function to set. Seems when doing this that it also solves problem 2 if you are running it on that word. If you run it on a region the red underline still remains.

Answer (score 1):

For the personal dictionary saving thing, I think you want to set the variable ispell-silently-savep to true (you can change it via M-x customize-group ispell).